# JRoute does not show the URL it is supposed to

Tags: joomla-3.x, jroute

I have the following problem:

I set a URL with JRoute like this:

```
 JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_gallery&view=gallery');
```

This gives me `example.site/gallery`, which is correct, however, if I want to display this same link, in a different view -  example  - view finishing, it does not show this same link, but it shows the link of the view "finishing" instead.

So, in short, if I'm displaying this `JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_gallery&view=gallery')` in the view "finishing", instead of displaying `example.site/gallery`, it displays `example.site/finishing`

Actually it happens with any link; if I do this: `echo JRoute::_('index.php')` it gives me `example.site/finishing`

UPDATE:

My Router File:

```
<?php


defined('_JEXEC') or die;

class GalleryRouter implements JComponentRouterInterface
{

    public function build(&$query)
    {
        $segments = array();
        if (isset($query['id']))
        {
            $db = JFactory::getDbo();
            $qry = $db->getQuery(true);
            $qry->select('alias');
            $qry->from('#__gallery_images');
            $qry->where('id = ' . $db->quote($query['id']));
            $db->setQuery($qry);
            $alias = $db->loadResult();
            $segments[] = $alias;
            unset($query['id']);
        }
        unset($query['view']);
        return $segments;
    }

    public function parse(&$segments)
    {
        $vars = array();

        $db = JFactory::getDbo();
        $qry = $db->getQuery(true);
        $qry->select('id');
        $qry->from('#__gallery_images');
        $qry->where('alias = ' . $db->quote($segments[0]));
        $db->setQuery($qry);
        $id = $db->loadResult();

        if(!empty($id))
        {
            $vars['id'] = $id;
            $vars['view'] = 'gallery';

        }

        return $vars;
    }

    public function preprocess($query)
    {
        return $query;
    }
}
```

Hidden menu links:

`index.php?option=com_gallery&view=gallery` which gives me: `example.site/gallery`

`index.php?option=com_gallery&view=finising` which gives me `example.site/finishing`

If I do an `echo JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_gallery&view=gallery')` in the view "finishing", instead of giving me `example.site/gallery` it displays `example.site/finishing`.

I'm not sure how JRoute works but as far as I know, it should display `example.site/gallery` regardless of the view it is being dispayed on, but pelase, correct if I am wrong.

Comment: Thiago could you add your router.php file to the question, and also the Link and alias in any menuitem (including hidden menuitems) which point to your com_gallery component. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, these are hiddden menu items.

Answer (score 0):

You can use your custom router code to find a menuitem which matches the view you enter in your `JRoute::_()` call, and I think it's easiest to do this in the `preprocess` method.

Add this code into your router.php `preprocess` method:

```
if (isset($query['view'], $query['Itemid']))
{
    $sitemenu = JFactory::getApplication()->getMenu();
    $targetView = $query['view'];
    $currentMenuitem = $sitemenu->getItem($query['Itemid']);
    if (strpos($currentMenuitem->link, "view=$targetView") === FALSE)  // if view doesn't match
    {
        $galleryMenuitems = $sitemenu->getItems(array("component"), array("com_gallery"));
        foreach($galleryMenuitems as $menuitem)
        {
            if (strpos($menuitem->link, "view=$targetView") !== FALSE)  // if this menuitem's view matches
            {
                $query['Itemid'] = $menuitem->id;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`$query['view']` is the view you asked for in your `JRoute` call.

`$query['Itemid']` is the `Itemid` associated with the current menuitem that the Joomla router is using – which is (probably) going to be the menuitem the user is on.

The code finds the `link` associated with the current menuitem, and if it doesn't match the view you're looking for then it gets all your component's menuitems and searches through them to find a link which includes your view.

Alternatively if all your component views are named the same as the corresponding menuitem `alias`, then you can easily find that using

```
$menuitems = $sitemenu->getItems(array("component","alias"),array("com_gallery",$targetView), true);
if ($menuitems)
{
    $query['Itemid'] = $menuitems[0]->id;
}
```

A guide to the Joomla menu/menuitems API is at https://docs.joomla.org/Menu_and_Menuitems_API_Guide